# import profiles for training a ML model in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, profile, hyperparameters

I'm working with some Machine learning models for which I'm using BayesSearchCV for tunning.

Instead of editing the main file, or pass all the parameters as values between many functions, I'm replacing this:

```
 opt = BayesSearchCV(
    XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic',),
            {
    'n_estimators': (50, 300),
    'learning_rate': (0.01, 0.3),
    'max_depth': (2, 7),
    'colsample_bytree': (0.3, 1),  
    'gamma': (0, 14)
})
```

by this:

```
    opt = BayesSearchCV(
        XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic'),


        parameters_range)
```

Where I import parameters_range as a dictionary from a settings.py file.

I want to do this as well with the other variables, which is not a problem, but I want to have predefined profiles, E.G.

quick search: where the search space is small
standard search: with a bigger range of variables

I'm not finding a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to save a dictionary is using inbuilt pickle module.

```
import pickle
parameters = {
'n_estimators': (50, 300),
'learning_rate': (0.01, 0.3),
'max_depth': (2, 7),
'colsample_bytree': (0.3, 1),  
'gamma': (0, 14)
}
pickle.dump(parameters,open('filename.pickle',''wb')
```

and then load it using

```
parameters = pickle.load('filename.pickle','rb')
```